# samba4 auto create uidNumber and gidNumber

Tags: samba

I would like to ask If anyone knows if it's possible to automaticly set the uidNumber and gidNumber and maybe even the other posix attributes nis-domain, home directory, login shell from server side. By that I mean like a "on create" hook, if empty, take next free uid. Also "on update" of the primary group, the gidNumber needs to get changed.

Comment: 4 years later, have you got this somehow?